# How to Implement Entity inheritence in SalesForce

Tags: custom-object

I would like to Implement Entity inheritence in `SalesForce`

Let us take the simple example of 3 java classes. Class `TwoWheelerVehicle` and `FourWheelerVehicle` are inherited from `Vehicle` Abstract class.

Not Sure how to acheive this.

Comment: Are you talking about in Apex code or in terms of the data model (i.e. Custom Objects)? Regardless, I'd be inclined to suggest that your example is one of those situations where I personally would favour composition over inheritance.

Comment: Thanks alex, I am looking for this setup in data model only. Actually i worked on one another framework, which supports this kind of configuration at data model level. that helped a lot in the application.

Comment: Alex, I have updated the actual scenario in one of the below Answers's comment. 
The sub-types would go to 4 -5 Levels. That's why i am mainly looking for Inheritence.

Answer (score 3):

If `Vehicle` is a class, you can use the `extends` keyword.

```
public class TwoWheelerVehicle extends Vehicle{
    ...
}
```

or

```
public class FourWheelerVehicle extends Vehicle{
    ...
}
```

- [Extending a Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_extending.htm)
- [Extended Class Example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_example.htm)

---

If you would prefer to deal with an `Interface`, you can use the `implements` keyword.

```
public class TwoWheelerVehicle implements Vehicle{
    ...
}
```

or

```
public class FourWheelerVehicle implements Vehicle{
    ...
}
```

- [Understanding Interfaces](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_interfaces.htm)

---

A key difference in Apex from most languages is:

> A class can only extend one other class, but it can implement more
> than one interface.

Keep that in mind when working with your classes.

Comment: +1.  Great point on the extending only 1 class.  Missed that in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The way this is done in Apex is by extending a class.

**From the documentation**

> A class that extends another class inherits all the methods and
> properties of the extended class. In addition, the extending class can
> override the existing virtual methods by using the override keyword in
> the method definition. Overriding a virtual method allows you to
> provide a different implementation for an existing method. This means
> that the behavior of a particular method is different based on the
> object you’re calling it on. This is referred to as polymorphism.

You can take a look at the documentation below

[Extending a Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_extending.htm)

Depending on your specific use case, you could also use an Interface to achieve this.

**From the documentation**

> An interface is like a class in which none of the methods have been
> implemented—the method signatures are there, but the body of each
> method is empty. To use an interface, another class must implement it
> by providing a body for all of the methods contained in the interface.
> Interfaces can provide a layer of abstraction to your code. They
> separate the specific implementation of a method from the declaration
> for that method. This way you can have different implementations of a
> method based on your specific application.

You can check out the documentation for that below

[Interfaces](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_interfaces.htm)

Comment: here is my scenario...

`Vehicle` Custome Object(Entity) would be having very Generic fields like Regestration Number, Owner of the vehicle(`Contact`), etc., `TwoWheelerVehicle` hold it's own specific fields... and `FourWheelerVehicle` also...

Now I wanted to show all the vehicles ContactA owns irrespective of it's subtype or sub-subtype.